# Lost all Elastic Search Indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

Yesterday when I wake up then I get too many emails from clients that they are unable to see any data. Later I found it that all elastic search data is gone. Then I have to reindex all data and it takes too much time. I am unable to figure out why it happened. Here are log entries:

I am using these versions in my rails application:

elasticsearch (1.0.2)

```
[2020-03-24 12:37:28,754][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x76418f78, /124.60.24.819:64731 :> /171.101.201.119:9300]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.cleanup(FrameDecoder.java:482)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:574)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:197)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.exceptionCaught(NettyTransport.java:532)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.exceptionCaught(MessageChannelHandler.java:229)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-03-24 23:11:35,216][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [samples] deleting index
[2020-03-24 23:11:35,244][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [cgi] deleting index
[2020-03-24 23:11:35,263][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [messagebroker] deleting index
[2020-03-24 23:11:35,278][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [acts_as_taggable_on_tags] deleting index
[2020-03-24 23:11:35,307][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [flex2gateway] deleting index
[2020-03-24 23:11:35,325][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [tasks] deleting index
[2020-03-24 23:11:35,389][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [website] deleting index
[2020-03-24 23:11:35,406][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [contact_associations] deleting index
[2020-03-24 23:11:35,540][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [decisions] deleting index
[2020-03-24 23:11:35,573][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [lcds] deleting index
[2020-03-24 23:11:35,589][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [lcds-samples] deleting index
[2020-03-24 23:11:35,603][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [blazeds] deleting index
[2020-03-24 23:20:48,473][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [tasks] creating index, cause [auto(index api)], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2020-03-24 23:20:48,557][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [tasks] update_mapping [task] (dynamic)
[2020-03-24 23:20:48,829][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [meetings] update_mapping [meeting] (dynamic)
[2020-03-24 23:23:16,449][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [tasks] update_mapping [task] (dynamic)
[2020-03-24 23:23:16,470][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [tasks] update_mapping [task] (dynamic)
[2020-03-24 23:24:10,820][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [ubuntu.members.linode.com] [acts_as_taggable_on_tags] creating index, cause [auto(index api)], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
```

**Mysteriously it happened both on staging and production servers. They are hosted on different servers**

Comment: Some questions: (1) do you have any scheduled job that could have triggered index deletion at any time? (2) who else have permissions to delete indices? (3) is your elasticsearch cluster publicly exposed?

Comment: 1: I have checked my server crontab -l. But did not found any rake task that deletes indexes. We are running elasticsearch for 4+ years. Did not experience this before. 
2: Are you talking about Ip Address 123:2:26:66/9200 output?

Comment: My questions (2) and (3) can be merged into: can you rule out that someone deleted those indices on purpose?

Comment: This is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: You think and error and index deletion events are related?

Comment: given error and index deletions are ~12 hours apart they are probably unrelated

Comment: Could someone have hacked into your cluster? Is it properly secured, was it opened to the outside world? 1.0.2 is a very old version that is not maintained anymore...

Comment: Yes this could be the reason. My cluster info is accessible publically

Comment: Can you check if [this old ransomware attack](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3157770/after-mongodb-attack-ransomware-groups-hit-exposed-elasticsearch-clusters.html) applies to you, i.e. if you can find one index with a ransom message in it? What does `GET _cat/indices` give you?

Answer (score 1):

Summarising what we learned from the comments to your original question, the elasticsearch cluster was publicly exposed and with no restrictions to operations. Given the abundant offer of tools like Shodan and other port scanners, it seems likely that your cluster was attacked by some malicious user.

Comment: Then how can I investigate that?

Comment: I guess that's a very different question than the one originally posted. AFAIK, Elasticsearch doesn't provide access logs out of the box. Do you have anything in place between the Internet and your cluster (e.g., reverse proxy)?

Comment: I would add that you can check whether your cluster was publicly exposed by grabbing your public IP and putting it into the search box on https://beta.shodan.io

And if you have a membership you can click on the "History" tab to see when a given port was first seen online.